# How many artifact lands can I play a turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I bought the [5 artifact lands](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&type=+%5bartifact%5d+%5bland%5d||subtype=+%5bartifact%5d+%5bland%5d&set=|%5b%22Mirrodin%22%5d) from *Mirrodin* to add to my artifact deck; it works with the artifact theme (having all of my cards be artifacts) and goes well with my [Darksteel Juggernaut](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=209011)s.

The thing is, the other day a friend told me that, because they are artifacts and not basic lands, I could play a basic land and as many artifact lands as I have in my hand in a single turn. Is this true?

I find it hard to believe as that would make then overpowered and everyone would use them.

Can anyone verify this or point me to an article where artifact lands are discussed?

Comment: As an aside, they *are* overpowered, just not for that reason, and were banned from the standard format when they were new and are banned from the new 'modern' format presently.  Just mentioning, don't be surprised if your friends get irritated by how easily you kick their butts using a metalcraft deck powered up by Mirrodin lands :)

Comment: @Affe I created an artifact deck and thought it was cool that I could make every card an artifact :) I have no metal craft and was using them as normal land until my friend told me they had other rules. On a side note some of the people I play have spent over £200 a deck and have 20 + mythic in them and have attempted to use over half the banned list lol

Comment: @Skeith You can do pretty cool things with artifact lands, like [tutor for them](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=209040), [sacrifice them](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=194239), [count them towards Affinity](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=205277), [count them towards Metalcraft](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=227508) and various other things that key on having an artifact on the battlefield!

Comment: Tried my artifact deck over the weekend and had 2 33/33 dark steel juggernauts on the field :) very overpowered with artifact land

Comment: I think your friend has artifact lands and Moxes confused - you can play one land per turn unless something specifically says you can play more - basic land, artifact land, snow land, or any other land, it's still one land per turn.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Artifact lands may be artifacts, but they are also lands, and all the usual rules about how often you can play and land (i.e. once a turn, on your turn) still apply to them.  The same goes for creature lands like Dryad Arbor from Future Sight: if you've played a land already that turn, you can't then play your Dryad Arbor.

If you want to dump out a ton of mana production on your first turn, you're going to have to invest many thousands of dollars for a large collection of Moxes, I'm afraid to say.

From the Comprehensive Rules, section 305, Lands:

> 305.2. A player may normally play only one land during his or her
>   turn; however, continuous effects may increase this number. If any
>   such effects exist, the player announces which effect, or this rule,
>   applies to each land play as it happens.
>
> 305.9. If an object is both a land and another card type, it can be
>   played only as a land. It can't be cast as a spell.

Essentially, the fact of an Artifact Land being an artifact doesn't mean it is no longer bound by the rules for lands; it must follow all the normal rules for lands, and all the normal rules for artifacts too - so it is a valid target for Shatter, and so on.

Comment: Oh, I don't know, there are a *ton* of cards which allow you to dump a bunch of lands down or otherwise [accelerate your mana](http://wiki.mtgsalvation.com/article/Mana_acceleration) without investing in Moxes. ;)

Comment: @ghoppe - Good point, I've changed my answer to say "on your first turn".  Obviously there are ways to ramp your mana if you're willing to work hard at it; the OP seemed to be looking for an easy short cut, and THAT doesn't exist except at a price :D

Comment: @Skeith: Also, it sounds like your friend has the idea that basic lands have different rules than nonbasic lands when it comes to playing them; this is not true. Rules-wise, the only differences between basics and nonbasics is how many cards with the same name you're allowed to play in your deck, and the supertype or lack thereof.

Comment: Technically, the newly-unrestricted Fastbond allows you to dump a bunch of lands into play on the first turn, too.

Answer (score -3):

Just because artifact lands are artifacts it doesn’t mean you can just spam them on your turn. The normal land rule applies to these lands meaning you can only place one land each turn unless other card texts say otherwise. If wanting to create lots of mana in early turns, expensive cards such as moxes and other 0 mana costing cards that produce mana - like black lotus - would be needed

Comment: I don't really see how this adds anything over the 10 year old existing answer.